# How to get the text to be at the bottom left of a div

Tags: html, css

This is the current result I am getting
[image]

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="activity_title_hours">
    <div class="activity_title">
        The Gym
    </div>
    <div class="activity_hours">
        - 5 Hours
    </div>
</div>
```

and this the relevant css:

```
.activity_title_hours{
    display: flex;
}

.activity_title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%
}

.activity_hours {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I am trying to get the text to be as follows

**The Gym - 5 Hours**

but with "The Gym" underlined

I have tried adding the following to my activity_hours class:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for width or float styles, simply use flex properties to the parent to make alignment or positioning

```
.activity_title_hours{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

.activity_title {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.activity_hours {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `inline-block` displays will give you a better result, in this case.

```css
.activity_title_hours {
    display: block; /* Or simply remove this style block. */
}

.activity_title,
.activity_hours {
    display: inline-block;
}

.activity_title {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}   

.activity_hours {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity_title_hours">
    <div class="activity_title">
        The Gym
    </div>
    <div class="activity_hours">
        - 5 Hours
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set the same `line-height` to both div's then the text will be next to eachother.

by adding the following to the activity hour class you can align the div (in an absolute way) to the bottom left.

I made my answer with the minimal change to your original code. But you probably can get a better solution with a bit of changed html/css.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 300px;
```

```css
.activity_title_hours{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
}

.activity_title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%
}

.activity_hours {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity_title_hours">
    <div class="activity_title">
        The Gym
    </div>
    <div class="activity_hours">
        - 5 Hours
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this and now the text is in the bottom left corner of the screen like so https://gyazo.com/13e9ee9f2cb221d6e0978c5bc2a22923

Comment: nah i wanted it lined up against the bottom left of the div that it is in, in this case activity_hours

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to have have one part of the sentence underlined you can use a `span`. This element is set to `display:inline` by default and won't change the format of a text when used. You can apply your css to this element then, e.g. `text-decoration:underline`. If the rest of your `div` is empty, you can just use a `padding` to get your text at the bottom left.

```css
.activity_title_hours{
    font-size: 35px;
    background: red;
    padding: 50px 50px 10px 10px;
}

.activity_title {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity_title_hours">
    <span class="activity_title">
        The Gym 
    </span>
    &nbsp;- 5 Hours
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The most simplest solution I can see is setting up `margin-top: auto`. You just need to wrap text with an additional
`div`

## JSFiddle Example

https://jsfiddle.net/oq0nk7w2/

## CSS

```
.activity_title_hours{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.bottom-container{
    margin-top: auto;
}

.activity_title {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.activity_hours {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="activity_title_hours">
    <div class="bottom-container">
        <span class="activity_title">
            The Gym
        </span>
        <span class="activity_hours">
            - 5 Hours
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.activity_title_hours {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.activity_title {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.activity_hours {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="activity_title_hours">
  <div class="activity_title">
    The Gym
  </div>
  <div class="activity_hours">
    - 5 Hours
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add  `**display: flex; align-items: center;`** to **`.activity_hours`** if you want position in center, or align-items: flex-end; to position at the bottom. Or you can use padding-top in *.activity_hours to position as you want.